# D3 Tree ON event issue using MOUSEOVER

Tags: d3.js

I have a nearly complete albeit sloppy code example using D3 to display an org chart via a collapsible tree.  You can see the result via this codepen entry:  https://codepen.io/tbellmer/pen/jOEarBa

```
enter code here
```

While the .ON enter works to expand and contract the code, that is not the case for ON MOUSEOVER and MOUSEOUT.  You can see that code at line 1032 of the codepen.

I am very open to improving the code and really do not like what I have for text placeholders starting at line 908.  Really ugly hack but since I am new to this, not sure how to best rewrite it.

Any suggestions and assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `nameval.text( d.data.name)` - the layout places all the node's bound data into a data property (which would help avoid collisions, keep bound data clear from layout data, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `handleMouseOver` and `handleMouseOut` functions need to be modified to call the `.text()` method. Currently your code was just adding a `text` key to your selections. Instead you should call the `.text("<text to be displayed>")`. At the same time your mouseout needs to set the text method with null parameter `.text(null)`.

```
   // Create Event Handlers for mouse
   function handleMouseOver(d, i) {  // Add interactivity
      nameval.text(d.data.name);
      useridval.text(d.data.userid);
      titleval.text(d.data.title);
      addressval.text(d.data.address);
      cityval.text(d.data.city);
      stateval.text(d.data.state); 
      zipval.text(d.data.zip);
      phoneval.text(d.data.phone);
      emailval.text(d.data.email);
      managerval.text(d.data.manager);
   }

    function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
      nameval.text(null);
      useridval.text(null);
      titleval.text(null);
      addressval.text(null);
      cityval.text(null);
      stateval.text(null);
      zipval.text(null);
      phoneval.text(null);
      emailval.text(null);
      managerval.text(null);
   }
```

[Working codepen.](https://codepen.io/Coola/pen/QWwOpJR)

Comment: Can you tell me why I need the .data. in d.data.name?  I have never seen a 3 level object like that before.

Comment: This happens when you call `d3.hierarchy`. It transforms your data by passing your data to a `.data` key and assigns `height`, `depth` and other attributes for the treemap. You can see what is the exact data binding by checking the variable where `d3.hierarchy` is called, which in your case is `root` so try `console.log(root)` after you declare the `root` variable to see the detailed data structure.